# Integrating .net Library into Objective C iOS App

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, embeddinator

This is the Github library : https://github.com/mono/Embeddinator-4000

which i am currently using for implementing few C# developed API in Objective - C ?

error EM0009: The feature `Returning type TextReader from native code` is not currently supported by the tool ?

Kindly help to fix this issue .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing Dll file and then used Emebidinator terminal command to generate necessary objective c file and then creating bridging header , did solve my issue.